# Notifying an individual when unit tests fail

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration

We are trying to figure out a way to reorganize our unit tests and want to work out a useful way to assign responsibility to the programmer for the unit tests they're in charge of.

This would be useful when our build breaks because one of our unit tests fails. We would like to automatically notify the (programmer/tester/intern chained to the desk) that they are responsible for breaking the build.

Does anybody have some advice on implementing such functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's Visual Studio Unit Testing framework has an "Owner" attribute.  We use it like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[Owner("developer@email.com")]
public void unit_test_name()
{
    //test body here
}
```